# how do i test my async jasmine/nodejs/promise code using Spies

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a module (example has been simplified) called process-promise which has a single function that takes a Promise as input and processes it - it also calls other functions using modules outside it as follows:

```
//<process-promise.js>
let User = require('user-module'); 

let processPromise = (promiseObj) => {
        let user = new User();

        promiseObj.then((full_name) => {
            const [ fname, sname ] = full_name.split(' ');

            if (fname && sname) {
                user.setDetails(fname, sname);
            } else{
               console.log('nothing happened');
            }

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    };

module.exports = {
processPromise
};
```

I am trying to unit test the above function using Jasmine, Rewire and Jasmine spies as per following code

```
let rewire = require('rewire');
let mod = rewire('process-promise');

describe('process-promise module', () => {

beforeEach(() => {

    this.fakeUser = createSpyObj('fake-user', ['setDetails']);
    this.fakeUserMod = jasmine.createSpy('fake-user-mod');
    this.fakeUserMod.and.returnValue(this.fakeUser)

    this.revert = mod.__set__({
        User: this.fakeUserMod
    });

});

    afterEach(() => {
        this.revert();
    });


    it('fakeUser.setDetails should be called', (done) => {
        mod.processPromise(Promise.resolve('user name'));
        done();
        expect(this.fakeUser.setDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith('user','name');
    });

});
```

I expect that the Spy this.fakeUser.setDetails should get called but i get the message from Jasmine "Expected spy fake-user.setAll to have been called with [ 'user', 'name' ] but it was never called." - the problem seems to be the fact the promise is Async but i've included the done function as other SO questions have suggested but this doesn't seem to resolve the problem for me.  What's the issue with my code? most other SO questions relate to angular so don't help with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, the promise is asynchronous and then `done` function in your test is called before the promise resolved to a value. The `done` function is used as a callback to tell the test engine, that all your asynchronous code has completed. It should be called after the promise **resolved to a value** (or failed for that matter).

In order to do that, you'd need to make the following adjustments to your code:

```
//<process-promise.js>
let User = require('user-module'); 

let processPromise = (promiseObj) => {
        let user = new User();

        // return a promise, to allow a client to chain a .then call
        return promiseObj.then((full_name) => {
            const [ fname, sname ] = full_name.split(' ');

            if (fname && sname) {
                user.setDetails(fname, sname);
            } else{
               console.log('nothing happened');
            }

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    };

module.exports = {
    processPromise
};
```

The test would then look like this:

```
    it('fakeUser.setAll should be called', (done) => {
        mod.processPromise(Promise.resolve('user name')).then(() => {
            expect(this.fakeUser.setAll).toHaveBeenCalledWith('user','name');
            done();
        }).catch(done);
    });
```

Be sure to add `.catch(done)`.  This will make sure your test fails in case the promise resolves to an error.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick and helpful response. the changes you suggested worked great and this has solved my testing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is probable that, by the time your test code execute, *the promise has not propagated to the code under test*. And simply calling `done()` doesn't the synchronization magic.

I'm not familiar with `rewire` so I will share an example using
[proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire)

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('process-promise module', () => {
    const fakeUser = { setDetails: jasmine.createSpy('setDetails') };
    const fakeUserMod = jasmine.createSpy('fake-user-mod').and.returnValue(fakeUser);
    const promiseObj = Promise.resolve('user name');

    beforeEach((done) => {
        const processPromiseMod = proxyquire('process-promise', {
            'user-module': fakeUserMod,
        });

        processPromiseMod.processPromise(promiseObj);

        promiseObj.then(() => done());
    });


    it('fakeUser.setDetails should be called', () => {
        expect(fakeUser.setDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith('user','name');
    });
});
```

Also note that `setAll` doesn't exist in the `fakeUser` instance. I guess you mean `setDetails` instead of `setAll`.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the suggestion! Had I not resolved it with rewire i definitely would have investigated the proxyquire method you suggested here.